# Sublime Text 3, Emmet, and Shopify's Liquid. Can it Work?

Tags: sublimetext3, shopify, liquid, emmet

I'm trying to get Emmet to use Liquid variables correctly.  For example, when I type,

```
div>ul>li.{{product.handle}}*5
```

it gives me:

```
<div>
  <ul>
    <li class="">{ product.handle }</li>
    <li class="">{ product.handle }</li>
    <li class="">{ product.handle }</li>
    <li class="">{ product.handle }</li>
    <li class="">{ product.handle }</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I'm using "HTML (Liquid)" syntax if that helps at all.  And I also know that anything between `{ }` will input normal text into the markup.  So I'm hoping that there's either a character you can use or that Emmet settings can be modified somehow.

Comment: Sometimes they use `{{{` instead of `{{`. I have faced this issue in SparkPost. Try with 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @HymnZ you are correct. Feel free to make an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes they use `{{{` and `}}}` instead of `{{` and `}}`. I have faced this issue in SparkPost. Try with 3 parentheses instead of 2.